# Exception: Parameter 'index' must be a int

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying to insert a row in a MySQL database using PDO, and I'm using parameter binding, but I'm getting a stranger error. The important functions are:

```
private static function getConnection() : \Pdo
{
    $con = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;charset=utf8', 'myuser', 'mypassword');
    return $con;
}

public static function runBool(string $query, ?array $bind = []) : bool
{
    return self::getConnection()
        ->prepare($query)
        ->execute($bind);
}
```

As you can see, `getConnection()` is only returning a connection (and it's working fine), the problem is with the function `runBool()` which is throwing an error on the `->execute($bind);` line:

> Exception: Parameter 'index' must be a int

For example, my `$query` is

> INSERT INTO client (company_id, name, phone, cpf, rg, city_id, address, obs) VALUES (:company_id, :name, :phone, :cpf, :rg, :city_id, :address, :obs)

And my `$bind` is

```
array(8) {
    ["company_id"]=> int(1)
    ["name"]=> string(3) "John Doe"
    ["phone"]=> string(11) "123456789"
    ["cpf"]=> string(0) ""
    ["rg"]=> string(0) ""
    ["city_id"]=> int(79)
    ["address"]=> string(0) ""
    ["obs"]=> string(0) ""
}
```

I've already tryed to `foreach` `$bind` and to use `bindParam()` or `bindValue()` individually, and then run `execute` but I get the same error on the `execute()`.
I've already included `:` before each key of the array and removed it (following [this comment](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.execute.php#71929)), but nothing changes.
I've already searched a lot on Google but nobody seems to have the same type of trouble.

Info:

- PHP 7.1.12
- Ubuntu 16.04.03
- MySQL 5.7.20
- Vagrant 2.0.0

Every help is appreciated.

---------------- EDIT ----------------

As asked, I've checked my namespaces, but I'm using \Pdo, so I think it's the native PHP PDO class. Here's the `var_dump` of `self::getConnection()->prepare($query)`:

> object(PDOStatement)#90 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(149) "INSERT INTO client (company_id, name, phone, cpf, rg, city_id, address, obs) VALUES (:company_id, :name, :phone, :cpf, :rg, :city_id, :address, :obs)" }

And here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpf` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rg` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `obs` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `client`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `city_id` (`city_id`),
  ADD KEY `company_id` (`company_id`);
ALTER TABLE `client` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `search` (`name`,`phone`,`address`,`cpf`,`rg`,`obs`);
ALTER TABLE `client` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `search_basic` (`name`);

ALTER TABLE `client`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=613;

ALTER TABLE `client`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `client-city_id` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `city` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `client-company_id` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES     `company` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: Sounds like the structure contains a field called `index` which is marked as a key or a unique.  Though it's odd to name a field index when it's a keyword in mysql

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PDO, so the tag is removed

Comment: Which structure? There's no collumn, table, variable or whatever called "index".

Comment: I think it's about PDO cause it occurs in the PDOStatement::execute() function.

Answer (score 1):

Change your $bind variable to

```
array(8) {
    [":company_id"]=> int(1)
    [":name"]=> string(3) "John Doe"
    [":phone"]=> string(11) "123456789"
    [":cpf"]=> string(0) ""
    [":rg"]=> string(0) ""
    [":city_id"]=> int(79)
    [":address"]=> string(0) ""
    [":obs"]=> string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it! See Example #2 on PDOStatement::execute reference page: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @dchao5 care to explain how does error message provided correspond with this wrong answer?

Answer (score 1):

First check what PDO are u using, check namespaces, because error that u get it's not a PDO error, it is a Phalcon result set error, here is a git: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/ext/phalcon/mvc/model/resultset.zep.c#L366

Phalcon try build a `result_set`.

Can you provide `var_dump` of `self::getConnection()->prepare($query);` before executing.

And provide DDL of your table.

Comment: Wow, that'll help me a lot. I'll just be able to test it in about 10 hours, but seems the right way to be looking at. I thought I was using the pure PHP PDO, but I can mistakely be using some Phalcon class.

Comment: I've just edited my question with the var_dump, it seems that I'm using the native PHP PDO class, but it's stranger cause I'm do using the Phalcon Framework, so it can be related.